# Removing tab from Toolbar in Winforms application

Tags: .net, winforms, toolbar, infragistics, ribbon-control

I am working on Winforms application. On it I have placed Infragistics UltraToolbarManager.

Now I just wanted the Ribbon on my form ,not the ribbon Tab and File Tab as its the only ribbon control and nothing is there in the File menu. So I just wanted to remove tabs coming along with it as in image below (pointed by red arrow) and leave the ribbon.

[image]

Comment: It's an integral part of what a ribbon is.  To remove it would be quite odd for users.  Reconsider your choice of controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with hiding the application menu and initializing creation filter class that will skip the rendering of the first tab header.
More about [how to use creation filter.](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2014.2/CLR4.0/html/Win_Creation_Filter.html)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.ultraToolbarsManager1.CreationFilter = new MyCustomCreationFilter();
        this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Office2007UICompatibility = false;
        this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolbarStyle.Office2013;
        this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Ribbon.FileMenuStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.FileMenuStyle.None;
}

class MyCustomCreationFilter : IUIElementCreationFilter
{
    public void AfterCreateChildElements(UIElement parent)
    {

    }

    public bool BeforeCreateChildElements(UIElement parent)
    {
        if (parent is TabRowUIElement)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```